# Telegram calls via Dante socks5 proxy server not working

Tags: proxy, telegram, socks5

I've confugured Dante 1.4on Ubuntu 16.04 as a socks5 proxy for Telegram.

Chats are working, but voice calls are not, failing at "Connecting".

Is there something special I need to configure in order to proxy Telegram voice traffic?

I'm using a single non priveleged (>1024) TCP/UDP port + login + password for connection.

Thats piece of log while i am trying to call somebody:

```
Apr 15 23:05:38 (1523736338.510915) danted[22977]: info: pass(1): udp/udpassociate [: username%USER@0.0.0.0.0 192.168.1.30.36562

Apr 15 23:08:33 (1523736513.020190) danted[22989]: info: pass(1): udp/udpassociate [: username%USER@0.0.0.0.0 192.168.1.30.49065
```

I can answer the call at destination device but connection is looping and getting error after 30 seconds

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These settings solved my problem of calls

Dante Server 1.4.2 (Ubuntu 16.04)

/etc/sockd.conf

`logoutput: /var/log/socks.log`

internal: 192.168.1.14 port = 8912
external: 192.168.1.14
socksmethod: username
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody


`client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}`

`client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}`


`socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        command: bind connect udpassociate bindreply udpreply
        log: error connect disconnect
}`


`socks block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}`

iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT

With these settings, you can already call from the telegram client desktop.
In the telegram app In the proxy settings Disable the "Use for calls".

Comment: Did you install from source?

Comment: Yes, version 1.4.2 is not in the official repository ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your pass/socks pass section with client-rule "command:" content: bindreply, udpassociate and udpreply

https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.4.x/sockd.conf.5.html

command
              The rule applies to the given commands.  Valid commands are
              bind, bindreply, connect, udpassociate and udpreply.  Can be
              used instead of, or to complement, protocol.  The default is all commands valid for the protocols allowed by the rule.